# CountTO in Javaascript

Tags: javascript

I've got countto function and it works fine when it's once in the code. I'd like to place it twice for vnumber1 and vnumber2, if I put vnumber1 code it works, if I put vnumber2 code - it works, but if they are one by one it doesn't work, what is missing in the code? I'm rookie. Blow it's the code:

```
clearInterval(intervalProgress);
$('.web1-step2').slideUp();
$('.web1-step3').slideDown();
$('.userJS').html($('.username-input').val());

$('.vNumberJS').countTo({
    from: 10,
    to: $('.vNumber-input').val(),
    speed: 1000,
    refreshInterval: 1,
    onComplete: function(value) {
        $('.vNumberJSthick').css('opacity', '1');
        $('.vNumber2JS').countTo({
            from: 10,
            to: $('.vNumber2-input').val(),
            speed: 1000,
            refreshInterval: 1,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                $('.vNumber2JSthick').css('opacity', '1');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.web1-step3').fadeOut(function() {
                        $('.web1-offers').fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The vNumber2 code, if I delete it it works fine, i'd like to put them both, whats wrong?

Comment: What is `$.countTo()`? google shows me several plugins. Wich one do you use?

Comment: And make sure to also add the framework (incl version number) to the tags. This will immensly improve your chancen of people helping you!